# time difference php Call to a member function format() on string

Tags: php, html, datetime, datetime-format

calculating the time difference in minutes and seconds but the error occurred says Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a string.

```
 <?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
echo "Time" . date(" h:i:s") . "<br>";
echo "Date " . date("d-m-y") . "<br>";
$now = date("i:s");
echo $now ."<br>";

$nearest = "03:30";
$nearest-> format("%i : %s"); 
echo $nearest  = $nearest->diff($now);
?>
```

Comment: $nearest is not a datetime object it is a string

Comment: try this  $nearest = new DateTime("03:30");

Comment: I tried but gives warning says DateTime::diff() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface. I convert both variables as DateTime format. not woring

Answer (score 2):

Date `diff()` expects `DateTime` object

```
<?php
    // Set timezone
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');

    // Current date time
    $now = new DateTime();
    echo "Now: " . $now->format("h:i:s") ."<br>";

    // Date Time to compare
    $nearest = new DateTime("03:30");
    echo "Nearest: ". $nearest->format("h:i:s") ."<br>";

    // Difference between dates
    $difference = $nearest->diff($now);
    echo "Difference: " . $difference->format("%h hours %i minutes %s seconds");
?>
```